# Break out shared model in code igniter applications

Tags: php, codeigniter, shared-libraries

I'm fairly new to code igniter and to php (coming from a java background).

I want to create a model that's shared by three apps that may or may not run on the same machine.
So I want to keep the model classes portable to be shared by all three and easily handled by SCM systems.

So my thought was to do the following:
If I have already broken the applications out into separate directories to share CI:
/var/www/app1
/var/www/app1/models
/var/www/app1/controllers
...
/var/www/app2
/var/www/app3
/var/www/system

then create a shared folder to put the model in:

/var/www/shared/models

Now I could either hack CI to look for the models there, or I could use symlinks, ie
/var/www/app1/models -> ../shared/models
/var/www/app2/models -> ../shared/models
/var/www/app3/models -> ../shared/models

I'm new to the inner workings of PHP, so I'm thinking at minimum this will create a performance hit because the model files may be loaded up to 3 times (maybe 4), or at worse this'll just barf because there's 4 copies of files named the same thing.

Is this a bad idea? Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you considered using [Kohana](http://kohanaphp.com) instead? Kohana was initially a fork off CI but it has become an excellent framework on its own. The [cascading filesystem](http://docs.kohanaphp.com/general/filesystem) feature that you can't find in any other web frameworks is really helpful to have multiple applications to share models/views/controllers/libraries/helpers etc.

Here is how I would do it in Kohana 2.x:

- Upload the system and modules folders into a location outside of http root, e.g `/apps/kohana/system` and `/apps/kohana/modules`
- Put the application folder somewhere nearby, e.g. `/apps/kohana/applications/app1`
- Set up the `/public_html/index.php` to point to the 3 folders.

> ```
> $kohana_application = '../apps/kohana/applications/app1';
> $kohana_modules = '../apps/kohana/modules';
> $kohana_system = '../apps/kohana/system';
> ```

- Now just throw the model that you want to be shared among your apps into `/apps/kohana/system/models/`. Or if you want to restrict to only some apps, create a module for example `/apps/kohana/modules/mymodule1` and configure those apps to use the module.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Lukman.
How's the stability and scalability of Kohana?
As a fork off CI, does it get enough exposure to be tested in a lot of different production environments?

Comment: Actually, never mind. I checked out the site and the forums - it looks very active and the tutorials are great.
Thanks for the answer.

Comment: How is this an answer to the CodeIgniter question?

Comment: StackOverflow is not all about answering the question exactly. It's about solving programming problems. If CodeIgniter cannot solve the problem, I gave a better alternative. I am myself an ex-codeigniter user who migrated over to Kohana because of my frustration on codeigniter shortcomings.